# Minimal FOSS RTOS with TCP/IP, SSL, USB and basic file-system support for ARM

Tags: networking, embedded, arm, rtos

Here's a candid admission first -- that I know zilch about RTOS or Embedded programming, so folks who know better may help me frame the query more appropriately.

What would be the minimal FOSS RTOS (or any OS for that matter) with support for TCP/IP, SSL, USB and some basic file-system for low-end ARM devices like Cortex-M3's ?

Have not ruled out something like ARM9/ARM7TDMI, so an RTOS that has "optional" MMU support, may be a major plus. We are at present dabbling with few uncertainities like precise processor, MMU/no-MMU, running completely head-less (no display), however I wanted to start a little ramp-up.

Would gladly answer counter questions to clarify the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that eCOS has support for all you need and is scalable.

Alternatively you could build from a self-selected kit of parts; choosing independent RTOS, filesystem, USB, etc. From different sources, and integrating them yourself.

Comment: Thanks @clifford. Will certainly look up eCOS. 

In my initial search 3 options had popped up -- uCLinux, FreeRTOS and eCOS. Wondering if anyone has any comparison of those options.

Regarding choosing independent RTOS, FS, USB etc., would appreciate some pointers, if possible.

Comment: Did some reading around eCOS, and found that 'USB host' mode is available only as a (rather expensive) commercial license, and there is no FOSS alternative. Apparently (almost) same is true for GUI lib (which I didn't mention earlier). Also, reading to see if ARM VFP (Vector Floating Point) is supported by eCOS, didn't find a confirmation, although not sure if eCOS per-se as an RTOS needs to do anything specific to support VFP.

Comment: @mike.dinnone char*, int*, void*

Comment: @jonathon-reinhart, care to expand ? I do understand the significance of char* & void*, but how does it help my cause.